# call function after filling form and pressing enter

Tags: javascript

In script below

```
<html>
 <body>
    <form>
        First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" maxlength="30" >
    </form>
    <button onclick="procesText()">get name</button>

    <script>
    function procesText()
    {
      var y = document.getElementById("myText");
      alert(y.value);
      y.value="";
    }
    </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

i want to call function procesText Not by clicking `get name button`, but by clicking enter when i fill input with text. How to achieve that?

Comment: and the horribly difficult search query is: `javascript call function by clicking enter`

Comment: _clicking enter_ what do you mean?

Comment: @RahilWazir i mean press enter key on keyboard

Comment: @maciekm You can submit it by pressing enter key. Change your `<button type="submit"` and place it inside `<form></form>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" maxlength="30" >
</form>
```

JS: (If you want to send the form to te server) ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YGqu8/))

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = procesText;
```

JS: (If you don't want to send the form to te server) ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YGqu8/1/))

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function(e) {
    procesText();
    e && e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thx for help, especially for the tip to not sent form to server.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the button, call the function onsubmit, and prevent it from submitting:

```
<form onsubmit="return procesText()">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" maxlength="30" />
</form>
<script>
    function procesText() {
        var y = document.getElementById("myText");
        alert(y.value);
        y.value = "";
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwwyv/)</kbd>